# Polynomial ring over an arbitrary set

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

I have the following exercise:
"Let $S$ be an arbitrary set and $K$ a field. Show that the polynomial ring $K[S]$ is a unique factorization domain."
My question is, how one defines such a polynomial ring? Every element as a variable? There are no conditions on cardinality of this set.

Comment: I suppose it denotes the free algebra over the free commutative monoid $\mathbf N^{(S)}$, i.e. the polynomial ring $K[X_s]_{s\in S}$.

Comment: The free commutative monoid is rather the submonoid of *finitely supported functions* $S\to\Bbb N$ of the monoid $\Bbb N^S$ of all functions.

Comment: @Berci If you're responding to Bernard, I assume that is what Bernard meant by the parentheses around $S$ in $\mathbf{N}^{(S)}$, though I suspect the clarification will be helpful to future readers.

Comment: Also an equivalent definition is that if $F$ is the left adjoint to the forgetful functor from $K$-algebras to $\mathbf{Set}$, then $K[S] = F(S)$.

Comment: Ahh, didn't notice the parentheses :) Yes, it's probably that.